# Reverse Power Rule integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Ok, so I am confused about the following;

When we have a polynomial, say $P(x)$, and we want to solve an integral where $P(x)$ is raised to a certain power, for example; $$\int (P(x))^adx$$Why can we not integrate it using the fact that integration is a reverse operation of differentiation? If we wanted to differentiate $(P(x))^a$, then it would result in the following; $$aP'(x)(P(x))^{(a-1)}$$ So my question is why can we not integrate the above function like so; $$\frac{(P(x))^{(a+1)}}{(a+1)(P'(x))}?$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all integration is not the reverse operation of differentiation. The theorem of fundamental calculus connects both operation in a handy way, but that's not the same as saying they are the reverse of each other.

About the computetation:

Your mistake is that you forget about the denominator $(a+1)(P'(x))$ which you have to take into consideration when differentiating the term $\frac{(P(x))^{a+1}}{(a+1)*(P'(x))}$ by using the chain rule. That's why your idea doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The power of a polynomial is always a polynomial and the integral of a polynomial is always a polynomial. Therefore the result will be a polynomial.

If your idea works, then the fraction should be a polynomial. So when could $P'(x)$ divide $P(x)$?